# Understanding (>>=) . (>>=)

Tags: haskell, monads, function-composition

I'm trying to understand `(>>=).(>>=)`, which GHCi tells me is:

```
(>>=)       :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
(>>=).(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (m b -> (a -> m b) -> b1) -> (a -> m b) -> b1
```

can you provide a step by step explanation on how the result is derived?

And is this composition ever used?

**Update:**

I am able to work out `fmap.fmap` but not quit `(>>=).(>>=)`, I'm able to get to `(.)(>>=) :: Monad m => (a1 -> m a) -> a1 -> (a -> m b) -> m b` but afterword things start to get a little confusing. Any help would be appreciated, just trying to learn here.

Comment: Have you tried deriving it yourself? Where did you get stuck? There are many questions already on Stack Overflow that show step by step how to derive types, such as [How (fmap . fmap) typechecks](//stackoverflow.com/q/23030638)

Comment: The return value should be `b1`, not `b`.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that?

Comment: @dfeuer It's not. It's only ___similar___.

Comment: @Zeta, I don't even see much similarity. This one seems tied to `Monad ((->) a)`, for one thing. `fmap . fmap`, `foldMap . foldMap`, and `traverse . traverse` are all similar to each other, but this seems quite different.

Comment: @dfeuer that's because `(>>=)` takes a function as its second argument, if we use the flipped version instead (which like `fmap`, `traverse`, `foldMap` maps a function to a function) `(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b` we get the following `(=<<) . (=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m (m a) -> m b` which is quite similar to `fmap . fmap` or `traverse . traverse`. Also notice that `((=<<) . (=<<)) return = join`. In fact `(=<<) . (=<<)` is very similar to `foldMap . foldMap`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**: We use the `((->) r` monad instance inbetween.

---

We have to look at `(.) (>>=)`. So let us first repeat the types:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> ((a -> m b) -> m b)
(.)   ::            (y  -> z                 ) -> (x -> y) -> (x -> z)
```

Therefore, we have

```
(.) (>>=) :: Monad m => (x -> m a) -> (x -> ((a -> m b) -> m b))
-- or, with less parentheses
(.) (>>=) :: Monad m => (x -> m a) -> x -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Now, we plug in another `(>>=)`:

```
(.) (>>=) :: Monad m => (x ->  m a               ) -> x -> (a -> m b) -> m b
(>>=)     :: Monad k => k i -> ((i -> k j) -> k j)
```

But now we have  a problem. We have `Monad m => m a` and `((i -> k j) -> k j)` at the same position. Is that even possible? Well, it's possible if there is a monad instance for

```
Monad k => (->) (i -> k j)
```

Turns out there is one, namely

```
instance Monad ((->) r)
```

for any `r`.
Now our outer monad `m` is `((->) (i -> k j)`, therefore we replace all occurences of `m` by `(i -> k j) ->`:

```
(.) (>>=) ::             (x -> (i -> k j) -> a) -> x -> (a -> (i -> k j) -> b) -> (i -> k j) -> b
(>>=)     :: Monad k => k i -> ((i -> k j) -> k j)
```

Now set `x ~ k i`, `a ~ k j` and we end up with

```
(.) (>>=) ::             (x -> (i -> k j) -> a) -> x -> (a -> (i -> k j) -> b) -> (i -> k j) -> b
(>>=)         :: Monad k => k i -> ((i -> k j) -> k j)
(>>=) . (>>=) :: Monad k => k i -> (k j -> (i -> k j) -> b) -> (i -> k j) -> b
```

Last, we rename `k` to `m`, `i` to `a` and `j` to `b2`, and we end up with

```
(>>=) . (>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (m b2 -> (a -> m b2) -> b) -> (a -> m b2) -> b
```